# how to remove error parameter 2 need to be an array()

Tags: php, json, api

i have data in $this->tags
something like that

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tag_id] => 18
                    [tag_slug] => basic-of-scene
                    [tag_name] => basic-of-scene
                    [tag_description] => 
                    [contact_count] => 1
                    [show_as_preference] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tag_id] => 17
                    [tag_slug] => basic-of-photo
                    [tag_name] => basic-of-photo
                    [tag_description] => 
                    [contact_count] => 1
                    [show_as_preference] => 0
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tag_id] => 16
                    [tag_slug] => basic-of-nature
                    [tag_name] => basic-of-nature
                    [tag_description] => 
                    [contact_count] => 1
                    [show_as_preference] => 0
                )
)
```

### and I used this code

```
if(!in_array($course->post_name,$this->tags,true)){
                    $tag_args = array(
                        "tags"=>array($course->post_name)
                    );
                    $id = $gr->create_tag($tag_args);
                    if($id){
                        $this->tags = $course->post_name;
                        $tag_ids[]=array('tag_id'=>$id,'tag_name'=>$course->post_name);
                        update_post_meta($course->ID,'vibe_wplms_groundhogg_tag',$id);
                    }
                    else{
                        $id = array_search($course->post_name,$this->tags);
                        $tag_ids[]=array('tag_id'=>$id,'tag_name'=>$course->post_name);
                        update_post_meta($course->ID,'vibe_wplms_groundhogg_tag',$id);
                    }
                }
```

it shows this error-----

"in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/class.init.php on line 248"
how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `stdClass Object` to array to make your array searchable

The easiest way is to JSON-encode your object and then decode it back to an array:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($this->tags), True);
```

or another way would be like

```
 (array)$this->tags;
```

These ways you can convert your stdClass object to an array and make it searchable using in_array function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are passing Object in the second parameter, convert it to Array and this should work;

```
if(!in_array($course->post_name,json_decode($this->tags,true),true)){
                    $tag_args = array(
                        "tags"=>array($course->post_name)
                    );
                    $id = $gr->create_tag($tag_args);
                    if($id){
                        $this->tags = $course->post_name;
                        $tag_ids[]=array('tag_id'=>$id,'tag_name'=>$course->post_name);
                        update_post_meta($course->ID,'vibe_wplms_groundhogg_tag',$id);
                    }
                    else{
                        $id = array_search($course->post_name,$this->tags);
                        $tag_ids[]=array('tag_id'=>$id,'tag_name'=>$course->post_name);
                        update_post_meta($course->ID,'vibe_wplms_groundhogg_tag',$id);
                    }
                }
```

Hope it helps!